# Installing rpm packages on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, package-management, software-installation, debian, rpm

Ubuntu, being a distribution derived from Debian, uses installer packages with extension .deb whereas other distributions like Fedora, CentOS, OpenSuse, Mandriva ... etc, use .rpm installers.

Many packages on the internet are only packaged in rpm.

If we have a system based on Debian as it may be Ubuntu it is possible to install these packages rpm in the system without harming it.

Comment: Yes, it's possible with `alien` but definitely not recommended. Most if not all generic software available as rpm is also packaged as deb. As a matter of fact it's much easier to find debs than rpms. Most software in rpm only is intended to a specific distro only. There's no point in trying to install it in Ubuntu.

Comment: It is true that some packages are only available as `.rpm`. In that case, install as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28235760/3585386).

Comment: @Alberto - I have undeleted this since it is useful to SE - the question is useful for people who are searching for an answer - SE will autoredirect to the duplicate question.  Thanks.